# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepsecurity'

Tags: python, deepsecurity

I am trying to use the sample Python code for a get request on the API to list all policies in the Deep Security Manager. I have replaced the sample code with my host and API key relative to our environment. Upon running the code I immediately receive the error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepsecurity'** in relation to the line **import deepsecurity as api**. Is there something from a deep security perspective that I need to install on my machine? Or how do I solve this error? Thank you

Comment: You need to install the deepsecurity Python package.

Comment: Try going here: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/fr/python?platform=on-premise   (may need to change your version/platform)